# Django celery task that will execute every day from 00:00 to 02:00

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I need to set up django celery task `my_task` that will execute every day from 00:00 to 02:00 with 5 minutes interval in this period. It seems it is unable to set up this task in admin via `django-celery-beat`. How to set it properly?

I need something like

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_task_1': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=5),
        'start': crontab(hour=0, minute=0),
        'expires': crontab(hour=2, minute=0),
        'args': (".."),
    },
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery's [crontab](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab) schedule class accepts the full [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) syntax, which, can be a bit hard to wrap your head around. This configuration should do what you want:

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_task_1': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour="0-1", minute="*/5"),
        'args': (".."),
    },
}
```

Note: that doesn't run the task at 2:00. I think the easiest way to achieve this is to add a second schedule:

```
    'my_task_2am': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour="2", minute="0"),
        'args': (".."),
    },
```

Comment: Beauty. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can run with celerybeat task that will run another celery task and do:

1. check current time if it is in 00.00 - 02.00 interval
2. if point 1 is True do your logic
3. run itself again with apply_async in 5 minutes.

What you will get, in 00.00 your celerebeat task will be run that initiate your another celerey task that will be do above logic until it's 02.00.

Comment: Thank you for idea!